# including a remote file in PHP

Tags: php, include

I am unable to include a remote PHP file in my PHP script. I suppose my hosting changed php settings.

The code I was using was:

```
include "http://domain.com/folder/file.php";
```

How do I allow enable the include function using php.ini/.htaccess ?

Is there any other workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I just checked and both allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are 'on' on my server.
Could there be some other problem?

Comment: WHat's the URL you are trying to include?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To allow **inclusion** of remote files, the directive [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) must be set to `On` in php.ini

But it is bad, in a security-oriented point of view ; and, so, it is generally disabled (I've never seen it enabled, actually)

It is not the same as [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), which deals with opening (and not including) remote files -- and this one is generally enabled, because it makes fetching of data through HTTP much easier (easier than using curl)

Comment: Depending on the serverconfiguration (version of PHP) . allow_url_include => Available since PHP 5.2.0. Deprecated as of PHP 7.4.0.

Answer (score 4):

To use remote includes, the [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) option must be set in php.ini

Be aware that if the remote server is php-enabled, you'll get the *output* of that remote script, not the script itself. If you do want to fetch the source, you could add a symlink on the remote server, e.g. `ln -s file.php file.php.source` and then make your include reference file.php.source instead.