# is there anyway to call function from website1 to website2

Tags: php

I'm not sure it is possible or not, but i try 
`include "http://www.abc.cm.my/function.php"` inside my php file and it not work.

my ideal is

i have a standard function file at my own website and all my clients web will include my standard function directly from my own website, then i no need to duplicate the function file to all my clients website, the trouble i facing now is, i need to change/update the function file at each/all of my clients website, it not hard but just many work to do.

hope you guys understand my situation and my English.

Comment: php is processes server-side, so if you tried to call to another website you would only see the rendered result.

Comment: Look into webservices. JSON, SOAP/XML, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [including a remote file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php)

Comment: thanks guy, it call 'remote file'

Comment: it is never a good idea to do remote file inclusion, there is an inherant massive security risk with enabling this feature across the internet, if you HAVE to do this, you should setup a VPN for secure network access.  Otherwise you should really just create an API service to run remotely and return results.

Comment: Dear RaggaMuffin, i'm just a PHP developer can you provide me any website about this, i'm sure if i google [API service] it come out many different info, but sure i will google it as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the [URL include wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) option in PHP on website1.  You'll need to make sure that the remote server (website2) is serving the raw PHP--so that when you open it in a browser at `http://website1/script.php` you see the plain PHP source code.

However this is generally a bad idea, since you normally only want the PHP to be visible server-side (normally you don't want to show your raw code to the world).  You could use network mappings / mounts to map the remote filesystem to a local drive, or it would be a bit better if website2 were only a LAN only visible to website1.

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows for this under certain conditions:

> ... URLs can be used with the include, include_once, require and
>   require_once statements (since PHP 5.2.0, allow_url_include must be
>   enabled for these) ...

[Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php)