# send a variable through url in Include

Tags: php

I am trying to send a variable "q" to a search page through url. but i get the error saying

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q={echo $q;}'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')

here is my code

```
    if(isset($_POST['q'])){
    $q= $_POST['q'];
    }

    require 'theme/header.php';
    require 'theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q={echo $q;}';
    require 'theme/footer.php';
```

can any one tell me the reason and a way to over come this problem.. thank you..

after doing this..

```
require 'theme/header.php';
//require 'theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q={echo $q;}';
require "theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q=$q";
require 'theme/footer.php';
```

i get the error

```
 Warning: require(theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q=saman): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dr7bf45v/public_html/search.php on line 17
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to go over a wrong way.

You are trying to accomplish remote including. (1. you must allow it: [including a remote file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php). 2. your link should looks like url).

Now you are trying to require `theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q=saman` it's mean that your script looking for file with name `search.php?q=saman`. Do you have that file? No. Only search.php.

But, I think, you are trying to pass variable to the file [scope](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). There a better way to this. Just [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it without extra params.

P.S. but if search.php receives value from GET and you need that result you could use [curl](http://php.net/curl) because remote including is dangerous.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
require 'theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q='.$q;
```

When you are using this...

```
require 'theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q={echo $q;}';
```

PHP is interpreting `{echo $q;}` literally, because it is encased in single quotes. Usually PHP will interpret `{echo $q;}` as you want in double quotes, but to be safe, use the `.` to tack something on to the end of a string. If you wanted to encase `$q` in double quotes without having to use the `.`, do it like this...

```
require "theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q=$q";
```

Comment: Thank you. but i get the error..

`Warning: require(theme/_modules/contact/search.php?q=saman): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dr7bf45v/public_html/search.php on line 17`  But  am sure i have the file search.php in theme/_modules/contact/

Comment: Update your post to hold the current code.