# How do I include a path of google client library in php

Tags: php

```
$r = set_include_path(get_include_path() . '\google-api-php-client-master\src');
echo $r;
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/AdExchangeSeller.php';

function __autoload($class_name) {
  include 'examples/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

when I am running it on browser its showing following error..
[image]

Comment: what is **dsads** ??

Comment: cant you post the error message as text here? easy to read that way

Comment: sorry for that..I edited my question

Comment: you have answer here [including a remote file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php)

Comment: I did not get anything with that..actually I installed google_client library by adding it in php/Pear folder and also give the path of library in php.ini  like this include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR\google-api-php-client\src" but still its showing an error..

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the path seperator when calling set_include_path, try this:

```
$r = set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '\google-api-php-client-master\src');
```

[Here is the documentation on set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

**Edit**

Did you restart Apache after making the change to your php.ini?

Comment: How do I installed this liberary??

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking... do you mean you have not downloaded this yet? https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: set_include_path is part of PHP, just copy and paste my code to replace the first line of the code you posted.