# Can't include remote php files into local ubuntu php project

Tags: php, ubuntu, include, lamp

I'm having problems while including php files in my php project.
I'm using LAMP to run my php website locally on my ubuntu operating system.
Everything works fine if I only try to include local php files, but it gives me problems if I try to include a remote file which is on my online website.

For example, it works if I include this file:

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
```

but if I upload this same file on my remote website and then I try to include it locally, it don't work:

```
<?php include "http://www.mywebsite.com/base.php"; ?>
```

The remote file has 755 permissions.
Is there any restriction on LAMP configuration which deny remote file inclusion?
This is very strange for me! :(
I hope you can help me!

Comment: I think `<?php include "base.php"; ?>` this should be work for.Have you tried?

Comment: I need to include the remote file and not the local file.
I already switch ON the 'allow_url_include' in php.ini file but it still doesn't work and I still can't include remote php file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

To include remote files , the directive `allow_url_include` must be set `on` in `php.ini`

Kindly go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1158392/6058881)

Hope this answers your query

**Update :**

Suppose , if you want to fetch the `code source`, you can add a `symlink` on the remote server,

> e.g. ln -s somename.php somename.php.source

and then make your include reference `somename.php.source` instead.

*the above suggestion credit goes to @PaulDixon*

**Update 1:**

Just a second thought with confusion

Instead of ,

```
<?php include "http://www.mywebsite.com/base.php"; ?>
```

Try this ,

```
<?php include 'http://www.mywebsite.com/base.php'; ?>
```

Or this ,

```
<?php include ("http://www.mywebsite.com/base.php"); ?>
```

Comment: I already did this, but it doesn't work! I also restarted apache, but nothing changed!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access to the remote server, I can only upload files on it. I can only control my local ubuntu installation.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet try the Update1 in my answer and update me please

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work! :(
This is a big problem for me because I really need to include this remote file in my local website.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet I can understand your ache in solving this , Wright now i'm at my work . if you can hold for few hours say 4-5 hours , i can access your pc say via team viewer and can see in detail . if you are ok with that ping me at jjmmrg at gmail dot com . Good luck mate

Comment: Thank you!! I sent you an email!