# Including remote HTML file

Tags: php

I'm working on a project and I want to include an HTML script which will hosted on Pastebin.

Something like:

```
include 'http://pastebin.com/raw/testiungshdhd';
```

I tried

```
fgets(fopen('http://pastebin.com/raw/asdasddaqwe', 'r'));
```

But negative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cURL:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Basic example:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: so is there no other way like as simple as the `include '';` ?

Comment: Its kinda include. You can write a function, for example curl_include() with string param and it works same as include then.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to enable setting php.ini file as:-

```
allow_url_include=On
```

Then there are couple of possible ways to achieve it:

Method 1:

```
<?php 
    include("http://pastebin.com/raw/asdasddaqwe"); 
?>
```

Method 2:

```
<?php 
    echo file_get_contents("http://pastebin.com/raw/asdasddaqwe");
?>
```

DO this only if you trust remote source file which you are trying to include.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `file_get_contents`:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://pastebin.com/raw/JyEcHhy2');
```