# PHP : Fatal error: Class 'x' not found in 'y' on line 'z'

Tags: php, require

Please explain what is the cause of the error could be..?

I can not see the class but, I didn't see any `require error`

```
    var_dump(12);
    require('http://dev.credicom.de/spreadsheet/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
    require('http://dev.credicom.de/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetReader.php'); 

    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader();
    foreach ($Reader as $Row)
    {
        print_r($Row);
    }
    die('priehali');
```

I am getting the following error :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetReader' not found in /www/htdocs/w00e163f/credicom.de.dev/content/importExcel.php on line 14
```

Comment: use relative paths

Comment: are you sure that `allow_url_include` has the value `On` in your php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

require should have the physical path to the file, not the URL

```
require(__DIR__.'excel_reader2.php');
```

Comment: [How to include a remote file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158348/including-a-remote-file-in-php)

Comment: require('/www/htdocs/w00e163f/credicom.de.dev/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetReader.php');  Tha same error

Comment: what is the current location of your file?
if your file in "/www/htdocs/w00e163f/credicom.de.dev/"
The require should be require('./spreadsheet/SpreadsheetReader.php');

Comment: Unless [allow_url_include](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) is set